# Mysql Stored procedure #1064 -You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Here I used Stored procedure for fetching my data.But I am getting #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Option",0Payment Method",0Payment Plan",0Type",0First Name",0TE",0tert",0Phone",' at line 1

please anyone help in this.

```
SELECT CONCAT('  
  SELECT createddate,formvalueid,locationid,authorid,maplocation, ',caption_column,'
    FROM forminputtable
  GROUP BY createddate,formvalueid,locationid,authorid,maplocation
  ORDER BY createddate desc'
)
INTO @query  
FROM  
(
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN caption =',actual_Caption,' THEN inputvalue END), '-') AS "',col_name,'"')) caption_column
  FROM (
    SELECT actual_Caption,  actual_Caption  AS col_name
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT caption AS actual_Caption FROM forminputtable) AS captions
  ) dates_with_col_names
) result;

    PREPARE statement FROM @query; 
    EXECUTE statement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

Comment: What ends up in @query? That appears to be where the syntax error is located.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: It would probably be better to state what your trying to achieve with this as there are all sorts of potential problems.  Especially trying to use a value from the database in an `as` clause as this has to be a valid column name.